# Is it possible to use IList(Of IList(Of String))?

Tags: vb.net, string, list, generics, interface

I'm trying to use a variable that is simply a list of a list of strings.
I've declared it as follows:

```
Dim iRows As New List(Of List(Of String))
```

Then I'm trying to pass it as a parameter to another method and I've defined the method as follows:

```
Public Sub Import(ByVal Rows As IList(Of IList(Of String)))
    For Each Row As IList(Of String) In Rows
        ImportRow(Row)
    Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, when I try to run that code I get the following error where it tries to pass my variable to my method.

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  Message="Unable to cast object of type     'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[System.String]]'."

When I change the method definition to use the types rather than the interfaces as follows, it works.

```
Public Sub Import(ByVal Rows As List(Of List(Of String)))
    For Each Row As IList(Of String) In Rows
        ImportRow(Row)
    Next
End Sub
```

So, is it not possible to use generics with interfaces in this way? It works fine as long as I'm not nesting them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it *is* possible to create an `IList(Of IList(Of String))` - but a `List(Of (List(Of String))` *isn't* one. Consider that in the latter case you could call

```
listOfLists.Add(arrayOfStrings)
```

as a string array implements `IList(Of String)`.

Basically this is exactly the same as considering an `IList(Of Fruit)` and a `List(Of Banana)` - a bunch of bananas isn't a fruit-bowl, because you can't add an apple to it.

In your case, you'd need to create a `List(Of IList(Of String))` instead - *or* declare an `IList(Of List(Of String))`.

Now interestingly, you *could* use a `List(Of List(Of String))` as an `IEnumerable(Of IEnumerable(Of String))` in .NET 4 due to *generic covariance and contravariance* - `IEnumerable(Of T)` is covariant in `T`. However, `IList(Of T)` is *invariant*.

Generic covariance and contravariance is a tricky topic. Eric Lippert has [written a great deal about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/) - using C# as the language rather than VB, but hopefully you can still understand it.

Comment: It all makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: It's really too bad Microsoft didn't implement an IReadableList base type for IList, since an IReadableList(Of Apple) would be usable by code expecting an IReadableList(Of Fruit).  Some pretty nasty runtime hacks would probably be needed to implement such a thing now without breaking existing code, though.

Comment: @supercat: Yes - it would have been useful. It's tricky - too much decomposition of the interfaces leads to confusion, but too little leads to this sort of thing :(

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I really dislike interfaces where there is a strong expectation that many implementations won't handle all members.  IEnumerable.Reset is just plain ugly.  Imagine if instead there were an IMultipassEnumerable which inherited IEnumerable, included Reset, and guaranteed that multiple passes with the same enumerator would yield identical data; the "contract" for IEnumerable could be weakened to specify that if a collection is changed during enumeration, an enumerator could either return 'sensible' data or throw an exception; an ILiveEnumerable would inherit IEnumerable but...

Comment: ...specify that it should return sensible data even if a collection is modified (rather than throwing an exception), and an IPurgeableEnumerable would provide a PurgeForAll method which would call a function on each element and delete all items for which the function returns true (a pattern which is often needed, but which can be difficult to implement without support in the enumerator).

Answer (score 2):

Start by declaring iRows like this:

```
Dim iRows As New List(Of IList(Of String))
```

Then, when you add a `new List(Of String)` to `iRows`, it will implicitly cast appropriately.

Comment: Your answer was exactly what I needed. Jon just explained it more. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -3):

Try the following change:

```
Public Sub Import(ByVal Rows As List(Of List(Of String)))
    For Each Row As List(Of String) In Rows
        ImportRow(Row)
    Next
End Sub
```

There doesn't appear to be a need to cast from `List` to `IList`.

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm, but this is not even close to what @Telarian is asking.